# Leaflet: route machine current position

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-plugins

I would like to insert the current position of the device at the first waypoint. With a function onLocationFound I get the position but I can't add it to the waypoint. Does not work.

is there a best solution?

```
function onLocationFound(e) {
        var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
        var curr_latitude = e.latitude;
        var curr_longitude = e.longitude
        L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map).bindPopup("You are within " + lat + " meters from this point").openPopup();
        L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
    }

function onLocationError(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

    map.locate({setView: false, maxZoom: 16});

map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

    map.locate({setView: false, maxZoom: 16});

L.Routing.control({

routeWhileDragging: false,
    draggableWaypoints: false,
    addWaypoints: false,
    waypoints: [
        L.latLng(curr_latitude, curr_longitude),
        L.latLng(45.5062563,9.1864641)
    ],
    language: 'it',
    showAlternatives: false,
    lineOptions: {
    styles: 
            [
                {color: 'black', opacity: 0.15, weight: 9}, //sombra
                {color: 'white', opacity: 0.8, weight: 6}, // Contorno
                {color: 'blue', opacity: 1, weight: 4}] // Centro
   },
          summaryTemplate:  '<h2>Percorso: {name}</h2><h3>Distanza: {distance}</h3>',   
          show: false,

}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: You didn't mention you are using Leaflet.Routing plugin (https://github.com/Turistforeningen/leaflet-routing). Demo at the plugin home page does not work. Can you provide working demo code (JSFiddle, ...)?